# How to obtain the number of tags in one element in xml using xml or java code

Tags: java, xml

My .xml doc contains data like this:

```
<Test-Set>
<Test-Case Name="Verify using Interface user in WebService we are able to do database transactions" />
<Test-Case Name="Verify using Interface user in JMS we are able to post a message to queue and get message from queue" />
<Test-Case Name="Verify using Interface user we are able to login BPD"/>
</Test-Set>
```

My expected output is: 3

Comment: Please show the code you have written, what result you expect, and describe the problem you are having. Otherwise we can't help you. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more info on creating a minimal, complete, and verifiable example, which will help us to answer your question.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, otherwise you will get downvotes

Comment: code is hidden due to improper indentation.If you observe edit is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml = "<Test-Set> " +
                     "<Test-Case Name=\"Verify using Interface user in WebService we are able to do database transactions\" />" +
                     "<Test-Case Name=\"Verify using Interface user in JMS we are able to post a message to queue and get message from queue\" />" +
                     "<Test-Case Name=\"Verify using Interface user we are able to login BPD\"/>" +
                     "</Test-Set>";
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
        String xpath = "count(Test-Set/TestCase)";
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        Double s = ( Double) xPath.evaluate(xpath, document, XPathConstants.NUMBER);
    }

}
```